# How to remove all of objects in Container on HPCloud-PHP 1.20

Tags: object, cloud, containers, removeall

http://hpcloud.github.io/HPCloud-PHP/doc/api/html/class_h_p_cloud_1_1_storage_1_1_object_storage_1_1_container.html#af7c3ea3150164bc92700134803f277be

They provide API to delete an object, but no way to delete all of objects in container. Because in the rule. if I want to delete Container, I have to make the container empty first.
Currently in order to deal with it, I have to get all objects in container and delete each of them, it means my site might do many requests just for removing a not-empty container.

I've posted some un-answered questions about HpCloud-PHP before, but maybe it is still new thing until now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there's no API call in Swift to delete a non-empty container.  You must iterate over all objects in the container and individually delete them you can delete the container.

There's lots of documentation for all the OpenStack APIs at [api.openstack.org](http://api.openstack.org/) as the PHP bindings are pretty much a straight mapping to API calls.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the CLI tool to force-remove a container regardless of its contents:

```
hpcloud containers:remove :demorama --force
```

Documentation on the object store CLI can be found [here for UNIX](http://docs.hpcloud.com/cli/unix/object-storage).  The main documentation page for the CLI may be found [here](http://docs.hpcloud.com/cli).  Good luck -- Dave